# remove double quotes wrapping from csv file in python and save to same file

Tags: text-files, filewriter, file-read, python-3.11, csx

i have csv file with data wrapped between double quotes, like the below. i want to transform the same file to remove these double quotes.

```
"a","b","c","d","f","g"
"1","2","1","4","7","6"
"2","3","3","3","5","7"
"4","5","2","2","5","5"
```

```
a,b,c,d,f,g
1,2,1,4,7,6
2,3,3,3,5,7
4,5,2,2,5,5
```

Comment: Use .join() will solve problem.